# Is it safe to .clear() then .push_str(aString) in Rust?

Tags: string, memory, rust

I'm a bit of a beginner to Rust and am trying to get my head around the `String` type.

I was just wondering if it is safe to do a `.clear()` before a `.push_str()` to push a larger string, IE: Can I guarantee that everytime the system will be able to increase the capacity despite using the same pointer? And is there (which there probably is) a better, possibly safer, way to overwrite a string with a larger one?

Comment: In general, if something is unsafe in Rust then it won't compile. You have to use the `unsafe` keyword to cause yourself any major problems - especially around memory safety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step by step:

- `String::clear()` is perfectly safe and sets the internal `Vec` (because that's what is behind `String`) to having a size (Not capacity) of zero
- `String::push_str()` then appends whatever you fed it to the end of that zero-size `Vec`, making sure to reallocate enough space should it overflow. Because the type itself is `&str` you can be pretty sure it'll work.

The only possible case is as follows: since `String` is an owned type and `&str` is an immutable borrow, your memory usage after `push_str()` will go up by the size of the `&str` you fed it unless your `String` was backed by a `Vec` with a capacity greater than that of the `&str`. That's to be expected. If you don't have that, your code will (evidently) trigger OOM.

So, yes, it is perfectly safe, and, honestly, the best way if you actually have `&mut String` and not the `String` itself :-)